# Single word for neutral tasting?

Tags: single-word-requests

My friend is a food blogger, we often go to new restaurants and try new food,but English is not our first language so I need help.

What can be a single word for food that is neutral tasting. Like if a dish is good in taste but with a little more seasoning it could have been better. So it's not really bad.

I would use the word bland but it seems a bit negative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.
Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: I've been looking for synonyms and antonyms for the similar words used but nothing fits, that's why I decided to post.

Comment: Add your research results to your post. Be detailed and specific. Where did you look, what did you find, why didn't it fit.

Comment: "fodder" ------

Comment: Their green curry was a little **pedestrian**.

Comment: @meta I think that's a valid question. I searched, no proper detail found anywhere.

Comment: @wayfaring interesting, I've never seen pedestrian used in reference to food. Is that valid??

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore It is used: https://www.google.com/search?q=pedestrian+cuisine&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: *bland* is what I'd use.  You *are* being "a bit negative" when you say the food would be better if it had more flavor. And *bland* is not saying it's distasteful- it's just not as "tasteful" as it could or ought to be.

Comment: @wayfaring I didn't knew that. You learn something everyday. Thanks

Comment: @Jim that was my original choice but after discussing over it, I got curious to know if we have some alternative.

Comment: Uninspired, unremarkable, tasteless, basically just stomach filler...  Good for your diet...

Comment: @Sunny It is not a valid question until the question post contains the results of the poster's attempts at research. Doing your own research first is expected of everyone who posts a question, as is including the results in the post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**plain**

[Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/plain)

> not decorated in any way; with nothing added: *The food is pretty plain (= prepared simply and without strong flavors), but there’s lots of it.*

---

**flat**

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flat)

> 7. a. : lacking flavor

e.g. *This dish tastes a little flat*

---

**insipid**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/insipid)

> 1. Lacking flavor: *mugs of insipid coffee*

---

**vapid**

[American Heritage dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=vapid)

> 2. Lacking taste, zest, or flavor; flat: *vapid beer.*

---

**savorless/savourless**

[thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/savorless)

> lacking taste or flavor or tang

---

**flavorless/flavourless**

[Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flavourless?a=british)

> having little or no flavour : *These grapes are completely flavourless.*

---

**I would say "plain/flat" is most neutral, "vapid/insipid" less so, and "savorless/flavorless" least so.**

---

some other options: **zestless, lacking tang, dry, dull, unsavory, plastic, garden-variety, so-so, humdrum, cut-and-dried**

---

Comment: Flat seems like the most fitting word so far. I thought about it too but was hoping there to be a better word. If no one suggests something better, I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks

Comment: yes. the thing about "neutral" is that "neutral" when it comes to food already has a connotation of "bad" because it's "not good" lol @Samy S.Rathore

Comment: Haha... that's true

Comment: @Samy S.Rathore ~ I just found "plain", it may just be the best fit and most neutral

Answer (score 14):

Personally I think **bland** is probably the right word for what you're describing, but if you think it's too negative, you could use **mild**. It's specifically used when describing food where the flavor is not as strong as it could be, but it's not negative, because some people prefer less seasoning.

Often but not always referring to heat, it can also mean a lack of strong seasoning or flavor. Mild implies the food is deliberately not strong-tasting as a matter of preference, rather than a lack of effort. *"The last curry I made was too spicy for you, so I made it mild this time. I think you'll like it."*

Comment: **Mild** is mostly used in conjunction with salsa.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that mild is used with lots of other things besides salsa.

Comment: *That's mildly interesting...*

Comment: I see what you did there...

Comment: I like this, I can't change the selected answer, but please have my upvote :)

Answer (score 7):

> What can be a single word for food that is neutral tasting. Like if a dish is good in taste but with a little more seasoning it could have been better. So it's not really bad.

You seem to be saying that there's not enough seasoning.

Well then it's **underseasoned.** Just say what you want to say :)

Example usage:

http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/food-and-drink/reviews/under-seasoned-soup-and-a-lame-duck-can-the-mains-at-manchesters-little-yang-sing-save-the-day-1764515.html

And in any case under- is a productive morpheme, meaning you can generate words with it, basically, at will.

> **under-**
>
> Prefix
>
> 2. Insufficiently; incompletely:
>
>    "Undernourished"
>
> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/under-

Obviously you can then modify this to soften it or be harsher to your heart's content: "a little underseasoned", "very underseasoned", "disappointingly underseasoned", "career-endingly underseasoned" etc. etc.

Answer (score 5):

I think you may use: ***[unseasoned](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unseasoned)***

> - (of food) not flavored with seasoning :
>     *a tasteless, unseasoned meal.*

Dictionary.com